# How to test if a bipartite density matrix violates Bell's inequality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, bells-inequality

For a given density matrix $$\rho = \sum_{ijkl=0}^1 r_{ijkl} |i,j\rangle \langle k,l|$$ describing a bipartite two-qubit system, how can I prove for what values $r_{ij}$ the density matrix violates Bell's inequality?

Comment: Is this an open research problem? I searched a bit, and it seems there are some criteria, but they do not appears constructive in nature, rather just existential.

Comment: Is it *the* Bell inequality (that's easy to find out by calculating the violation of the Bell inequality) or *a* Bell inequality?

Comment: There are various measures of entanglement https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504163. There are also some tests for density matrices that are stronger than Bell's inequality, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9604005

Comment: This paper answers your question: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/037596019500214N?via%3Dihub

Answer (score 1):

The density matrix you give is diagonal in a product basis - that is, it is described by a local hidden variable model. It thus will not violate any Bell inequalities, regardless of the value of $r_{ij}$.

Comment: I made a small mistake writing a density matrix in a diagonal product basis. I changed the density matrix how is it now?

Comment: Please do not edit the question in a way which completely alters its meaning. Post a new question. Otherwise I look like I did not read your question properly.